# No Login Required XMPP MUC

Tags: xmpp, xmppframework

I am working on a XMPP client that does not require the user to login and can join any permanent MUC. I understand it is possible to join an MUC anonymously but I think that still requires user to be logged in in the first place.

So here's what I want to do: I hope any user can use my client, only to set his/her desired display name, and can join any permanent anonymous MUC that has been created on my XMPP server.

Any help is appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Set up your server to accept [anonymous logins](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0175.html) - ejabberd, prosody, openfire - all of them supports anonymous logins.
2. `[xmppStream authenticateAnonymously:...]` do the trick on the XMPPFramework side